# java.policy allowing connection to port 80

Tags: java

I have added the following to /home/user/.java.policy

```
// https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html
grant {
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "169.254.170.2:80", "connect"; 
};
```

As far as I can tell this should allow me to get from that URL.

This is my code:

```
    URL url = new URL("http://169.254.170.2/v2/credentials/uuid");

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"))) {
        for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
            logger.error(line);
        }
    }
```

I still end up getting a `java.net.BindException: Permission denied` from the call to url.openStream:

```
    2021-06-02T17:12:52.010+10:00   java.net.BindException: Permission denied
    2021-06-02T17:12:52.011+10:00   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    2021-06-02T17:12:52.011+10:00   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:574)
    2021-06-02T17:12:52.011+10:00   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:563)
    2021-06-02T17:12:52.011+10:00   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
    2021-06-02T17:12:52.011+10:00   at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:648)
    2021-06-02T17:12:52.012+10:00   at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:597)
    2021-06-02T17:12:52.012+10:00   at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:182)
    2021-06-02T17:12:52.012+10:00   at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)
    2021-06-02T17:12:52.012+10:00   at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569)
    2021-06-02T17:12:52.012+10:00   at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    2021-06-02T17:12:52.012+10:00   at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:341)
    2021-06-02T17:12:52.013+10:00   at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:362)
    2021-06-02T17:12:52.013+10:00   at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1261)
    2021-06-02T17:12:52.013+10:00   at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1194)
    2021-06-02T17:12:52.013+10:00   at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1082)
    2021-06-02T17:12:52.013+10:00   at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1016)
    2021-06-02T17:12:52.013+10:00   at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1600)
    2021-06-02T17:12:52.014+10:00   at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1528)
    2021-06-02T17:12:52.014+10:00   at java.base/java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1167)
```

Is there something else that needs to be done to allow me to send a request to port 80? I'm using Java 15.0.2 from https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk

Comment: A `BindException` implies that you tried to *listen* to a port, not *connect* to it. Can you post a stack trace? I strongly suspect the code you posted isn't to blame here.

Comment: Ports below 1024 are privileged therefore your application will likely need to run as root to bind to port 80. Or another options see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10735/allowing-a-user-to-let-listen-to-a-port-below-1024

Comment: @JoachimSauer that is what I thought too but I'm just calling https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream-- (I'm using Java 15 but I doubt it has changed). I'll add the stack trace.

Comment: @JamesMudd yeah I can't run as root for security reasons.

Comment: @JoachimSauer This one came from a connect, not a listen.

Comment: This should work. Can you run it with `-Djava.security.policy.debug=policy` to see whether your policy file is actually active? Warning: there is a lot of output. Documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/troubleshooting-security.html).

Comment: @user207421 after a bit of reading I don't think it is a security policy thing (I think) - I think it's the OS (Linux in this case) not letting a non-root user use port 80. I don't think Java Security Manager is actually enabled because when I did enable it with a simple policy file, Java wouldn't even load my .jar file.

Comment: I agree. There is no `SecurityManager` in the stack trace, after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to a security tool wrapped around the java executable, not due to any issue with Java itself.